# "cannot generate code for file random.ads" when running a .adb program

Tags: gps, ada

I have some troubles with running a program in Ada. I have the three following project files (I use GPS) :

**Types.ads**

```
package types is
   subtype T_valeurind is Integer range 2..14;
   type T_couleur is (s, h, c, d);
   type t_carte is record
      valeur : T_valeurind;
      couleur : T_couleur;
   end record;

   type T_jeu is array (1..7) of t_carte;

   function trans(val: Character) return T_valeurind;

end types;
```

**Trans.adb**

```
with types;
use types;
WITH Text_Io , Ada.Integer_Text_Io;
USE Text_Io , Ada.Integer_Text_Io;


function trans(val : Character) 
   return T_valeurind is
   ret: Integer;
begin 
   case val is
     when '3' => ret:=3;
     when '4' => ret:=4;
     when '5' => ret:=5;
     when '6' => ret:=6;
     when '7' => ret:=7;
     when '8' => ret:=8;
     when '9' => ret:=9;
     when 'T' => ret:=10;
     when 'J' => ret:=11;
     when 'Q' => ret:=12;
     when 'K' => ret:=13;
     when 'A' => ret:=14;
     when others => null;
  end case;
  return ret;
end trans;
```

**Test.adb**

```
WITH Text_Io , Ada.Integer_Text_Io;
USE Text_Io , Ada.Integer_Text_Io;
with types;
use types;


procedure test is
begin
   put(T_valeurind'Image(trans('c')));
end test;
```

I'm just trying to execute test.adb just to check if my function "trans" works well. When I build the files in GPS, everything works just fine. But when I want to run them, I have the following message, and no execution :

> cannot generate code for file types.ads (package spec)
>
> gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
>
> [2018-12-02 02:01:39] process exited with status 4, 100% (2/2), elapsed time: 01.65s

But what is perturbing is that the first time I tried running the code, it worked. Without changing anything, it stopped working.
I don't know what to do. I've seen that this message just tells me that .ads file is not compilable, but what I try to compile and run is an .adb file, so I don't get it..
Do you have an idea why it doesn't work ?

Thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, those aren't project files, which would have type `.gpr`; they're Ada source files in your project.

Your `types.ads` promises `function trans`, which means it needs a package body in `types.adb`,

```ada
package body types is
   function trans(val : Character) 
      return T_valeurind is
      ret: Integer;
   begin 
      case val is
        when '3' => ret:=3;
        when '4' => ret:=4;
        when '5' => ret:=5;
        when '6' => ret:=6;
        when '7' => ret:=7;
        when '8' => ret:=8;
        when '9' => ret:=9;
        when 'T' => ret:=10;
        when 'J' => ret:=11;
        when 'Q' => ret:=12;
        when 'K' => ret:=13;
        when 'A' => ret:=14;
        when others => null;
     end case;
     return ret;
   end trans;
end types;
```

(Hmm. If you pass in an invalid character, you'll return uninitialised data, and as like as not get a `Constraint_Error`; `T_valeurind` includes the value 2, shouldn’t you cover it?)

Your `trans.adb` specifies a library-level function instead.

> When I build the files in GPS, everything works just fine. But when I want to run them, I have the following message, and no execution :

If a package spec (`types.ads`) requires a body (`types.adb`) and you don't provide it, the compiler will produce the message you report when you try to compile it. If you try to just *compile* `test.adb` it will be OK. If you try to *build* `test.adb` it will try to compile the package `Types` and will fail, regardless of whether you're trying to Build or Build & Run.

I have no idea how this could have worked first time!

Comment: If I understood well, since you talk of types.ADB, I have to create this file to put your code, right ?

Comment: That's what I tried, and it looks like it works. I have other issues now, but this problem is solved. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to include your `function Trans` in the context of the test program.  And if it isn't in the context, you can't use it.

Try to add:

```ada
with Trans;
```

To the context clause of `procedure Test`.

Comment: Well I tried with adding with Trans; at the beginning of my test.adb file, but it sends me that trans.adb is not found. Yet trans.adb is in the same folder (src). I think I misunderstood something about functions and their declarations...

Comment: It probably means that `trans.ads` isn’t found (to `with` a unit, there has to be a spec, in `.ads`)

Answer (score 0):

Your whole problem could have been avoided in the first place using powerful Ada enums capabilities (and some bad inputs handling strategy, like exceptions). Your `trans` procedure would be useless.

If you are interested in the order relation of your enum values, you can also use the Ada's **`'First`*** (first enum literal), **`'Last`** (last enum literal), **`'Pos`** (position inside the enum), **`'Succ`** (next enum literal), **`'Pred`** (previous enum literal).

If you perform memory mapping for your variables, you could use **`'Valid`** to check if the variable has a valid value and save the need of exception catch for constraint errors.

See example below:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Exceptions; use Ada.Exceptions;

procedure Hello is
    -- miwing chars and literal values in enum
    -- note that jack is 'J' and not the single source code character J
    type My_Awesome_Enum is ('1', '2', '3', 'J', Q, K, Ace);
    for My_Awesome_Enum use
       ('1' => -1,
       '2' => 2,
       '3' => 3,
       -- ...
       'J' => 11,
       Q => 12,
       K => 13,
       Ace => 14);
    temp : Integer;
    prev : My_Awesome_Enum;
    succ : My_Awesome_Enum;
    temp2 : My_Awesome_Enum;
begin
    -- ------------------------------------------
    -- Ada enum power
    declare
    begin
      for value in My_Awesome_Enum loop
        temp := My_Awesome_Enum'Enum_Rep(value);
        Put_Line("Enum litteral value: " & value'Image & " - memory representation: " & Integer'Image(temp));

        if value /= My_Awesome_Enum'First then
            prev := My_Awesome_Enum'Pred(value);
            Put_Line("Previous: " & prev'Image);
        else
            Put_Line("No previous");
        end if;
        if value /= My_Awesome_Enum'Last then
            succ := My_Awesome_Enum'Succ(value);
            Put_Line("Next: " & succ'Image);
        else
            Put_Line("No next");
        end if;
        Put_Line("");
      end loop;
    end;
    -- ------------------------------------------
    -- conversion from some input source
    Put_Line("");
    declare
        strInput : String := "Unknown user value";
    begin
        Put_Line("Handling of user input: " & strInput);
        temp2 := My_Awesome_Enum'Value (strInput);
    exception
    when E: others =>
        Put_Line("Exception catched: " & Exception_Information (E));
        Put_Line("Setting value to Ace instead");
        temp2 := Ace;
    end;
    Put_Line("tmp2 value: " & temp2'Image & " - memory representation: " & Integer'Image(My_Awesome_Enum'Enum_Rep(temp2)));
    -- ------------------------------------------
    -- mmemory mapping
    Put_Line("");
    declare
        my_int : Integer := -3;
        mapped_Enum : My_Awesome_Enum;
        for mapped_Enum'Address use my_int'Address;
        last_enum : My_Awesome_Enum := (My_Awesome_Enum'Last);
        stop_condition : Integer := (last_enum'Enum_Rep) + 2;
    begin
        while (my_int < stop_condition) loop
            if mapped_Enum'Valid then
                Put_Line("Enum with value: " & my_int'Image & " is valid.");
            else
                Put_Line("Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value: " & my_int'Image);
            end if;
            my_int := my_int + 1;
        end loop;
    end;

end Hello;
```

This give sthe following output (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_ada_online.php, with GNATMAKE v7.1.1):

Build:

```
$gnatmake -o hello *.adb
gcc -c hello.adb
gnatbind -x hello.ali
gnatlink hello.ali -o hello
```

Execute:

```
Enum litteral value: '1' - memory representation: -1
No previous
Next: '2'

Enum litteral value: '2' - memory representation:  2
Previous: '1'
Next: '3'

Enum litteral value: '3' - memory representation:  3
Previous: '2'
Next: 'J'

Enum litteral value: 'J' - memory representation:  11
Previous: '3'
Next: Q

Enum litteral value: Q - memory representation:  12
Previous: J
Next: K

Enum litteral value: K - memory representation:  13
Previous: Q
Next: ACE

Enum litteral value: ACE - memory representation:  14
Previous: K
No next

Handling of user input: Unknown user value
Exception catched: raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : bad input for 'Value: "Unknown user value"

Setting value to Ace instead
tmp2 value: ACE - memory representation:  14

Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value: -3
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value: -2
Enum with value: -1 is valid.
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value:  0
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value:  1
Enum with value:  2 is valid.
Enum with value:  3 is valid.
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value:  4
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value:  5
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value:  6
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value:  7
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value:  8
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value:  9
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value:  10
Enum with value:  11 is valid.
Enum with value:  12 is valid.
Enum with value:  13 is valid.
Enum with value:  14 is valid.
Memory mapping would result in invalid enum for value:  15
```

Comment: Well I'm new to Ada, so I do not understand all your code yet, but I keep it since I think it will be useful later. Thank you a lot for your time !

Comment: Basically, Ada provides features for enum conversion from/ to string and for enums memory representation. It saves the pain of writing and maintaining switch cases similar to the one you posted.

Comment: Note that if you don’t define a memory representation yourself, the compiler will define one itself.